# Skype doesn't work via Vodafone 3G in Egypt?

Tags: skype, 3g

I've bought 3G Vodafone modem in Egypt. Everything works fine except Skype. Skype just doesn't connect. I guess Vodafone just blocked Skype?

Do someone know how to workaround this problem?

Comment: It sounds like Skype is indeed being blocked.  I would contact Vodafone about this problem.

Comment: I have contact them and they say that it is not there problem , it Communication ministry prevent it and I think they lie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see this article, it might be useful for you:

http://almostfearless.com/what-to-do-if-skype-is-blocked-where-you-travel-and-why-we-should-care/

> #### How to Get Around It
>
> The work around is connect to a VPN.  A VPN bypasses the firewall, because after you make your initial connection (which your ISP can still deny) you have formed a private tunnel between your computer and your VPN’s server.  So when you go to use Skype you’re not going through the firewall at all.  You can basically do whatever you’d like.
>
> (…)
>
> #### Ways to Get a VPN
>
> There are tons of websites that offer this service for free, and my best advice is to just try out a few and see if they’ll work where you are.  Things change on a daily basis, so keep switching around if you hit a roadblock.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thank you very much !, I solved skype problem on my iPad using https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/free-vpn-hexatech-unlimited-vpn-proxy-for-iphone/id1053874290?mt=8